# How do I spawn a Slime that can be used as a soccerball in vanilla Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm wondering how to spawn a slime that has no AI and that can be pushed and knocked around like a soccerball. I've noticed that when I remove the AI it also loses any knockback effect.

Is there a way to do this? Whether via command or by other methods is fine by me. I'm in snapshot 15w42a.

Answer (score 3):

Ok I think I figured it out use this command:

```
/summon Slime ~0 ~1 ~0 {CustomName:Ball,CustomNameVisible:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:2,Amplifier:20,Duration:999999}]}
```

This spawns a slime that can't move anywhere, and then use a weapon with knockback enchantments.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my idea:
You spawn a slime, give yourself a knockback weapon 1 then an infinity bow with punch 8 or 9 for scoring the goal. And i think you need friendly fire to prevent knocking players away.

Comment: Uh... Bow = 1-shot kill slime if not invulerable.

Comment: oh, now i think of that! Silly me!

Comment: Also what's too stop it from moving around?

Comment: I guess Al? maybe that'll work